# Добавление в объект данных динамически

Tags: javascript

Есть код который добавляется динамически. Нужно из элементов input забрать значения и закинуть их в объект. Ключ должен быть название класса, а значение - value элемента

```
<div class="add-field-data">
<!-- Этот код добавляется динамически
  <div class="form-field multi-input-data">
   <input type="text" name="description[]" class="description" placeholder="Description">
   <input type="text" name="value[]" class="value" placeholder="value">
  </div> -->
</div>
```

Написал такую функцию, но она не добавляет данные.

```
const getData = () => {
    return Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.add-field-data'), function(el) {
        el.childNodes.forEach(function(el) {
            Array.prototype.map.call(el.childNodes, (element) => {
                return { [element.getAttribute('class')] : element.value };
            }) ;
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: А куда она должна добавлять? У вас объекта то нет

Comment: Как должен выглядеть результат?

Comment: {description: value,  description2: value2}

Answer (score 1):

Но если есть возможность, то класс в качестве ключа не стоит использовать, он там может быть не один. Лучше тогда data атрибут использовать.

```js
 const getData = () => {
    return [...document.querySelectorAll('.add-field-data input')].reduce((sum,item) => {
        sum[item.className] = item.value;
        return sum;
    },{})
}

console.log(getData())
```

```html
<div class="add-field-data">
  <div class="form-field multi-input-data">
   <input type="text" name="description[]" class="description" placeholder="Description">
   <input type="text" name="value[]" class="value" placeholder="value">
  </div>
</div>
```

Можно вывести массив объектов:

```js
   const getData = () => {
  return [...document.querySelectorAll('.add-field-data > div')]
    .map(el => [...el.querySelectorAll('input')].reduce((sum,item) => {
    sum[item.className] = item.value;
    return sum;
  },{}))
}

console.log(getData())
```

```html
  <div class="add-field-data">
  <div class="form-field multi-input-data">
   <input type="text" name="description[]" class="description" placeholder="Description">
   <input type="text" name="value[]" class="value" placeholder="value">
  </div>
  <div class="form-field multi-input-data">
   <input type="text" name="description[]" class="description" placeholder="Description">
   <input type="text" name="value[]" class="value" placeholder="value">
  </div>
  <div class="form-field multi-input-data">
   <input type="text" name="description[]" class="description" placeholder="Description">
   <input type="text" name="value[]" class="value" placeholder="value">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я извиняюсь. Но данных код получает только последние значение, а у меня их больше чем один. И они добавляются динамически при нажатии на кнопку "Добавить поле".

Comment: @Константин Ситников замените в моем коде add-field-data на родительский контейнер. У них же есть один общий контейнер?

Comment: add-field-data и есть родительский контейнер.  В нем динамически создаётся div class="form-field а внутри уже все остальное.

Comment: Если у вас все инпуты имеют только два класса, как показано в примере, то так и будет. Он будет перезаписывать данные в те ключи, которые уже существуют. Вам может следует структуру конечного объекта пересмотреть?

Comment: В какой момент вызывается функция?

Comment: По нажатию на кнопку расчитать.

Comment: Мне нужно собрать данные из полей. Как будет выглядит конечный объект не имеет значения

Comment: Могу предложить еще массив объектов. Дополнил ответ. Но всё равно лучше бы структуру самому написать, за вас тут никто додумывать не будет. Потому как ваш изначальный вопрос и эта структура {description: value, description2: value2} данных различаются.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const getData = () => [...document.querySelectorAll('.add-field-data')].reduce((obj, topEl) => {
    for(let formField of topEl.childNodes){
      if(!!formField.tagName){
        for(let input of formField.childNodes){
          if(input.tagName !== 'INPUT') continue;
          obj[input.getAttribute('class')] = input.value 
        }
      }
    }
    return obj;
}, {/*Это ваш объект, если вы хотите сюда добавить - прокиньте его в эту функцию как аргумент снаружи*/})


console.log(getData());
```

```html
<div class="add-field-data">
  <div class="form-field multi-input-data">
   <input type="text" name="description[]" class="description" placeholder="Description" value="description value">
   <input type="text" name="value[]" class="value" placeholder="value" value="value value">
  </div>
</div>
```